# Restar datos de un array a partir de otro array- Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo los siguiente 2 array:

Array 1:

```
var datos1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

Array 2:

```
var datos2=[3,5,7];
```

Lo que quiero es llenar un nuevo array donde se guarde los datos que no este presentes en el `var datos2`por ejemplo: `[1,2,4,6]`, estoy tratando de la siguiente manera pero no es como yo desearia que fuera:

```
 for(var j=0;j<datos1.length;j++){
     for(var k=0;k<datos2.length;k++){
         if(datos1[j]!=datos2[k]){
              datosNoRepetidos[j]=datos2[k];
          }
      }
}
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Para una proxima pregunta, siempre agrega el resultado que deseas obtener, y el resultado que estas obteniendo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sé que obtuvo una respuesta muy bien explicada y funcional pero este proposito también se podría lograr con el método [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para crear un nuevo `array` en base al resultado que retorne la condición. Que en el segundo `array`  no **!** [este incluido](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes) dicho elemento iterado. *(el)*

```js
var datos1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var datos2=[3,5,7];
var result = datos1.filter(el => !datos2.includes(el));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

a ver.. analicemos tu algoritmo...

El segundo for tiene la idea.. pero no esta completa.. Si vos grabas el valor en el array datosNoRepetidos la primera vez que no se repite, entonces vas a grabar todos los valores del segundo array. siempre.

O sea, vos comparas el 1 con el 3.. obviamente no son iguales.. entonces ya grabas el 3. la pregunta seria porque?

para empezar? deberias recorrer los array en orden inverso, es decir, buscar los que queres saber si estan o no, en el otro.. algo asi...

```
for(var j=0;j<datos2.length;j++){
     for(var k=0;k<datos1.length;k++){
         if(datos1[j]!=datos2[k]){
              datosNoRepetidos[j]=datos2[j];
          }
      }
}
```

Ahora, esto obviamente sigue sin solucionar tu problema.. porque falta.. algo que diga que no esta en ningun lugar del segundo array...

Para eso.. agreguemos un flag...

```
for(var j=0;j<datos2.length;j++){
     var esta = false
     for(var k=0;k<datos1.length;k++){
         if(datos2[j]!=datos1[k]){
              datosNoRepetidos[j]=datos2[j];
          }
      }
 }
```

Presupongamos que no esta.. de esta forma.. si no esta.. nunca se va a hacer true.. para hacerlo true.. hacemos lo siguiente...

Entonces, agreguemos un if, que nos diga si lo agregamos o no

```
for(var j=0;j<datos2.length;j++){
     var esta = false
     for(var k=0;k<datos1.length;k++){
         if(datos2[j]!=datos1[k]){
              esta = true
          }
      }
}
```

Si alguna vez se hizo true.. entonces esta en alguna posicion, y no nos sirve.

```
for(var j=0;j<datos2.length;j++){
     var esta = false
     for(var k=0;k<datos1.length;k++){
         if(datos2[j]!=datos1[k]){
              esta = true
          }
      }
      if (esta){
          datosNoRepetidos[j]=datos2[j];
      }
}
```

Ahora.. nos falta algo mas.. datosNoRepetidos[j] no esta bien.. tenemos que ir guardando en la ultima posicion de ese array, no en la misma posicion de los array que estamos recorriendo.. entonces.. agreguemos un contador.

```
var pos = 0
for(var j=0;j<datos2.length;j++){
     var esta = false
     for(var k=0;k<datos1.length;k++){
         if(datos2[j]!=datos1[k]){
              esta = true
          }
      }
      if (esta){
          datosNoRepetidos[pos]=datos2[j];
          pos = pos+1
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo de una manera simple con la función "union" de lodash:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#union

El código sería así.

```
let datos1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], datos2=[3,5,7];
let resultado = _.union(datos1, datos2);
console.log(resultado);
```